# Verificar se o valor do $_GET é um número Inteiro

Tags: php

Estou tendo dificuldade para verificar se o valor do `$_GET` é inteiro. Segue abaixo o código:

```
<?php
     $modo=$_GET['PG'];
     if(is_int($modo)){
         echo "e inteiro";
     }else{
         echo "n e inteiro";
     }
?>
```

Mesmo eu colocando um número no `$_GET`, ele sempre fica retornando que não é um `int`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode usar a função [is_numeric](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) do `PHP` que verifica se uma variável é um número, mesmo que ela venha como string.

Mas tem que se observar que ela vai verificar desde Hexadecimais até números Reais e binários como numérico `TRUE`

Answer (score 5):

O método `HTTP GET` retorna um array de strings passados pela `url` através da função `urldecode`.
Então sugiro outras formas de verificação, em caso de `$_GET['PG']` ser um número:

```
if(is_numeric($_GET['PG']))
```

Ou mesmo apenas se existe a variável desejada, usando `isset()`, que para paginação também funciona perfeitamente:

```
if(isset($_GET['PG']))
```

Answer (score 3):

Nesse caso o

```
$_GET['PG']
```

Ele retorna uma string por isso que esta sempre dando falso ...